# Is there a way through an excel formula to have it where a blank cell and a specific value show 0?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a cell that shows `=IF(ISBLANK($E12),1,0)` I have another that shows `=IF($E4="Total:",1,0)`

Is there a way to make them do the same thing, so if the cell shows 0 or Total: it shows 1, otherwise it will show 0, even if there is something else in it.

I thought there was a formula that would do that, but I don't have it in my collection...

If anyone could help scramble up something like that together it be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This'll do the trick:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK($E12),$E4="Total:"),1,0)
```

Comment: I've done some programming in the past, sometimes I really miss the IFWhile loops. Thanks.